# creating dynamic links and maintain them after refresh/reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am new in angularjs. This may be basic for you guys.
Actually, after filling the form, the submit button must create a new link.
The problem that i'm using

```
document.getElementById('myP').appendChild(newLink);
```

and it create a link after filling the form.But when i refresh the page it disappear.
When i refresh or load the page it must contain all the links that i have created before.
Is there a method that maintain my links?

Comment: Where do you store the link now?  Local `$scope`?

Comment: Here is my code:
<div>
    <p id="myP">Un peu de texte <a> et un lien</a></p>
</div>

and this is my controller:

 var newLink = document.createElement('a');
                    var newLinkText = document.createTextNode("Mon site");
                    newLink.id = 'sdz_link';
                    newLink.href = 'http://www.siteduzero.com';
                    newLink.title = 'Découvrez le Site du Zéro !';
                    newLink.setAttribute('tabindex', '10');
                    newLink.appendChild(newLinkText);
                    document.getElementById('myP').appendChild(newLink);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to store your link somewhere other than just on the page if you need it to persist.  There are a couple of options for that, which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24789419/3504957) explains, but my suggestion is to use [localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247130/how-to-store-the-data-to-local-storage) to hold the list of links.

Comment: But after that i need that my code generate buttons every time i clic on the sabmit button.
And the id and name of this new button will be the id and the name witch are added in the form.
So does this sollution still working with this?
And if so, how can i store my buttons?

Comment: It should.  You'll have to do some research to determine *how* best to store your data (an array of objects with properties for the link, id, and name of the button is where I would start), but localStorage is definitely a good *where* to store it.

Comment: thnx a lot @senschen i will try it this way.
If you have good documentation it'll be cool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on submit button:

```
$state.go('.', null, {reload:true});
```

This will reload your page on same state
use angular Js to save your data or to submit data

```
$scope.variable = {};
$scope.save = function (object) {
   Service.save(object, function () {
      $state.go('.', null, {'reload': true});
   });
};
```

Comment: @ojis

When i add  this code my link does not appear at all